# Groovy quine! How does it work?

Tags: groovy

[Quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29) is a self reproducing code. For example if the code in groovy looks like:

```
def s = 20
```

When i run the above code, i should get the program statements as my outputs. So the above code should produce:

```
def s = 20 //as this is my input..
```

As I have seen in [Groovy Console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/487001), i came to know groovy supports [Quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29) :

```
s='s=\\\';s[0..1]+s[3]+s[0..1]+s[2]*6+s[3..-1]*2';s[0..1]+s[3]+s[0..1]+s[2]*6+s[3..-1]*2
```

But I don't know how it works! Could any one say me, how the code in the above link works?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in question is:

```
s='s=\\\';s[0..1]+s[3]+s[0..1]+s[2]*6+s[3..-1]*2';s[0..1]+s[3]+s[0..1]+s[2]*6+s[3..-1]*2
```

So, the left statement defines a string, then the right statement adds together different bits of the String:

If we add the following to print out what it's doing:

```
println s[0..1]
println s[3]
println s[0..1]
println s[2] * 6
println s[3..-1] * 2
```

we get the output:

```
s=
'
s=
\\\
';s[0..1]+s[3]+s[0..1]+s[2]*6+s[3..-1]*2';s[0..1]+s[3]+s[0..1]+s[2]*6+s[3..-1]*2
```

And if you add all those strings together, you get the original program.

Comment: OK well said, but now we have to get the output two times right? First statement as it is(because it produces the output before without the `println`) and for the `println` statements!! But we get only one!! Confused ``_^

Comment: @ant Add all those 5 strings together.  it is the same as the input.  And there is no `println` statement, it relies on the fact that the groovyconsole prints the result of a script when there is no `println`

Comment: @ant Yes... something would need to print out the result of running this code

Comment: @tim: `1000.times { println "Thank you" }` ^_^